# Exception on using VectorAssembler in apache spark ml

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to create a vectorAssembler to create an input for logistic regression and am using the following code :

```
//imports
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors, VectorUDT}


1 val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
2 .setInputCols(flattenedPath.columns.diff(Seq("userid", "Conversion")))
3 .setOutputCol("features")

4 val output = assembler.transform(flattenedPath)
5 println(output.select("features", "Conversion").first())
```

Im getting the following exception on line 4 :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: error reading Scala signature of org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector: assertion failed: unsafe symbol SparseVector (child of package linalg) in runtime reflection universe
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler.unpickle(UnPickler.scala:46)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.unpickleClass(JavaMirrors.scala:619)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter$$anonfun$complete$1.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:28)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter$$anonfun$complete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:25)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter$$anonfun$complete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:25)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.slowButSafeEnteringPhaseNotLaterThan(SymbolTable.scala:263)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:25)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter.load(SymbolLoaders.scala:33)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$typeParams$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:140)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$typeParams$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:133)
at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:123)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$8.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:168)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.typeParams(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:132)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$8.typeParams(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:168)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$NoArgsTypeRef.typeParams(Types.scala:1926)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$NoArgsTypeRef.isHigherKinded(Types.scala:1925)
at scala.reflect.internal.transform.UnCurry$class.scala$reflect$internal$transform$UnCurry$$expandAlias(UnCurry.scala:22)
at scala.reflect.internal.transform.UnCurry$$anon$2.apply(UnCurry.scala:26)
at scala.reflect.internal.transform.Transforms$class.transformedType(Transforms.scala:43)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.transformedType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeApiImpl.erasure(Types.scala:225)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeApiImpl.erasure(Types.scala:218)
```

I'm using spark-mllib_2.11 1.6.0 jar

Any pointers on how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

The runtime reflection exception threw me off track. Turned out it was a maven dependency issue in another project where the current project was referenced.

I was able to resolve this by updating the project pom.xml.