# assertion failed: unsafe symbol TimeStamp (child of <none>) in runtime reflection universe

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jar, annotations

We use scala programing language and use spark as a data processing. we have 3 different projects

Project A // where we have defined this annotation

```
package Common {
      case class TimeStamp(format: DateFormat) extends StaticAnnotation
    }
```

Project B // where we have this case class which is using above annotation

```
case class CommonSchema(
    @Common.TimeStamp(DateFormat.DateTime)
    __datetime: Timestamp
)
```

Project C // where we use above case class as type

```
val events = events.map(c => CommonSchema(
  c.__datetime,
))
events.as[CommonSchema]
```

We are hitting the below exception in project C

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: error reading Scala signature of commonschema: assertion failed: unsafe symbol TimeStamp (child of <none>) in runtime reflection universe
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler.unpickle(UnPickler.scala:46)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.unpickleClass(JavaMirrors.scala:619)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter$$anonfun$complete$1.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:28)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter$$anonfun$complete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:25)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter$$anonfun$complete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:25)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.slowButSafeEnteringPhaseNotLaterThan(SymbolTable.scala:263)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:25)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter.load(SymbolLoaders.scala:33)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$typeParams$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:140)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$typeParams$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:133)
at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:123)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$8.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:168)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.typeParams(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:132)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$8.typeParams(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:168)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$NoArgsTypeRef.typeParams(Types.scala:1931)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$NoArgsTypeRef.isHigherKinded(Types.scala:1930)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType2(TypeComparers.scala:377)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType1(TypeComparers.scala:320)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType(TypeComparers.scala:278)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.isSubType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.$less$colon$less(Types.scala:784)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.$less$colon$less(Types.scala:260)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.isSubtype(ScalaReflection.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$optionOfProductType$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ScalaReflection.scala:677)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$optionOfProductType$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:676)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$optionOfProductType$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:676)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.optionOfProductType(ScalaReflection.scala:675)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
```

Similar questions are answered in [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56444263/what-does-this-mean-assertionerror-assertion-failed-unsafe-symbol-unstable) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620703/assertion-failed-unsafe-symbol-developerapi-in-runtime-reflection-universe), but We already build uber jar for project C, so all the classes should be included in the package. locally the unit test that hits this code works fine but why we get the runtime errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because were using maven-shade-plugin plugin and minimizing the jar. We made a config change so that this classes does not get removed from jar. And it has fixed the issue